# retrieve contents of div and make image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Is there a way to fetch the content of a div and place that ocntent in the 'src' parameter of an image? I'm working on a project that uses json to load translation files, and tehrefore I can't load an image directly, but figured I could at least load the image name.

So:

```html
<div id="flag-name" style="hidden">en-flag.jpg</div>

<img src="DIV CONTENTS HERE">
```

Ideas appreciated! (Am also using jquery so open to that as well)

Comment: JS or Jquery can do that for you.  Add the js code you're working with in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it in jQuery by getting the text  of the div and then setting the source of image like this:

```js
var source = $("#flag-name").text();
console.log("before - " + $("#image").attr("src"));
$("#image").attr("src",source);
console.log("after - " + $("#image").attr("src"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flag-name" style="hidden">en-flag.jpg</div>

<img id="image" src="DIV CONTENTS HERE">
```

Comment: @dilby Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The button demonstrates that ablility. Use the button's onclick code wherever you need.

```html
<div id="flag-name" style="hidden">en-flag.jpg</div>
<img id="myImage" />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src=document.getElementById('flag-name').innerText">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an event to start the jQuery/javascript -- so I added a button. Also, you will find it easier to target specific DIV and IMG tags if you give them IDs or classes.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var mySrc = $('#flag-name').text();
  $('img').attr('src', mySrc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flag-name" style="hidden">http://placeimg.com/300/200/animals</div>
<img src="DIV CONTENTS HERE">
<button>Go</button>
```